# java - compare two string to list and create new list

Tags: java, string, list, compare

If  have list with more than 100 elements such:

```
list.add(str);
```

Where we get str from loop.

If we have another two string such:

```
String strStart;
String strEnd;
```

Now we want to compare the two string with all list elements.
For exmp:
If the list contain **"Afg", "Alb","Ban"...**
and

```
strStart = "Alb";
strEnd = "Ger";
```

We want to create new list with

```
only this two string
and the string between theme.
```

Comment: And what is your question? What problem did you meet while implementing that?

Comment: I think that you want someone else solves your "problem" without thinking on it at all.
First of all, have you tried to use string comparison in a loop, or something else?

Comment: Ask a question there is no question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stw");
    String strStart = "def";
    String strEnd   = "mno";
    List<String> subList = list.subList(list.indexOf(strStart), list.indexOf(strEnd)+1);
    System.out.println(subList);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Eritrean, that what I want.